# What do I need to do to write a .csv file to a shared network folder? (Raspberry Pi & Python)

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, samba

I have 2 raspberry pis and a windows computer all on the same network. I have one raspberry pi set up as a NAS, and I want the other raspberry pi to run a program and then write a csv file containing data to a samba share on the NAS pi. Then I would be able to access the file from my windows computer and open it.

The following code will write the csv file called "lights.csv" to the desktop of the 2nd raspberry pi:

```
outputFile = open('lights.csv', 'w')
for i in range(len(button_array)):
    #Convert the button's time_on variable to a string and append a comma and newline.
    outputFile.write(str(button_array[i].total_time_on) + ',\n')

outputFile.close()
```

Is it a simple coding edit that I need? Do I need to import another Python module? Will this involve somehow "mapping the network drive?" I have not found a straight answer for this anywhere else, so I am trying to be as specific as possible. I also don't want to copy the file there (by using shutil), I want it to save/write it directly to that network folder, which is then shared using Samba.

Please be specific, and if possible, please show some example code for it. I am just a novice (at best) when it comes to Python, Linux, and networking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Samba file-system sharing is (and should be) completely invisible to a  standard application like your example. The sharing (mounting) should be done outside of the application, usually at system startup.

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module to write the csv file? Additionally, on linux, see if you can navigate to the network folder via terminal. If so, then you can retrieve the `path` via terminal command `pwd`, which you can then use in python as `os.path.join(network_folder_path, 'lights.csv')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the network drive. Once done it loads at system start as well. Also check if you have proper write access.

Follow the video tutorial here to build a NAS device using Raspberry Pi : https://youtu.be/yb3-ku8oXHk